# Handling test / training data in R when the levels of a variable differs

Tags: r, glm, predict

I'm not sure what the best approach to handling the following type of error is :

## code

```
a = LETTERS[1:4]
b = LETTERS[1:5]
n1 = 70
n2 = 30

s1 = sample(a, n1, replace = T)
s2 = sample(b, n2, replace = T)
s3 = rbinom(n1, 1, 0.5)
s4 = rbinom(n2, 1, 0.5)


train <- data.frame( x1 = s1, y1 = s3 )
test <- data.frame( x1 = s2, y1 = s4 )

m <- glm(y1 ~ x1, data=train, family = "binomial")

predict(m, test, type="response")
```

## error

```
 Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
 xlev = object$xlevels) : 

  factor x1 has new levels E
```

The above is a MWE of an error that I had in some code which happened to have a level in training data that wasn't present in the testing data. In the above example that's the level `E`.

What can I do in order to ensure that both dataframes have the same levels for each variable?

Comment: This will test if there any `x1` values in test that aren't in train `any(!test$x1 %in% train$x1)`. Is that all you want? I'm not sure exactly what kind of programming solution you are looking for.

Comment: thanks @MrFlick , but that's not enough, unless you're suggesting that in the event of there being no `x1` values I should discard the test / training data. I think that I need some way of having `E` (using the example in the OP) acknowledged by the training data even though it doesn't contain any of it's values, I'm not sure. I'm not sure how the `any()` suggestion you've given can be used to make the example in the OP function, I guess.

Comment: you can't predict on a value you've never seen before (without some modeling assumption). Are you looking for a novel statistical method? You might want to ask at [stats.se] instead then. Because what you are asking right now doesn't make any sense from a statistical stand point.

Comment: Well I'm not too sure... Perhaps it's more a statistics question than I anticipated as I suppose the question is now whether it's valid to consider a variable that's possible to be completely contained in test data, as that's what's happened to lead to this question.

Comment: That's a problem of bad study design -- not programming, really.

Comment: Yes it seems so, but I've learnt that from this thread